# Node sub-route returning 404

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, routes, pug

I have just started using node.js with the Express framework, and I am trying to understand how the built in routing works. I have found that a "main" router can be defined from which other "sub-routes" are used. For now, my app initially makes a get request that loads a dropdown from a MySQL database. I added a demo button that should take the value in the dropdown and make a request with it as a query parameter to my sub-route. When the button is clicked for the sub-route, I am getting a 404. 
My app.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var routes = require('./routes/index');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'pug');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', routes);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

// error handlers

// development error handler
// will print stacktrace
if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
  app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error', {
      message: err.message,
      error: err
    });
  });
}

// production error handler
// no stacktraces leaked to user
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error', {
    message: err.message,
    error: {}
  });
});


module.exports = app;
```

My index.js (main route):

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var models = require('../models');

router.use('/savings', require('./savings.js'));

/* GET home page with locations and their initial data collection dates */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  models.Location.findAll({
    attributes: ['locationName', 'initializationDate']
  }).then(function(locations) {
    res.render('index', { 
      title: 'Solar Data Savings',
      locations: locations
    });
  });
});

module.exports = router;
```

savings.js (sub-route):

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var models = require('../models');

/* GET calculate solar data savings and reroute */
router.get('/savings', function(req, res, next) {
  req.param('locationID');
  models.Bank.findAll({
    attributes: ['bankID'],
    include: [{
        model: Location,
        where: { locationID: Sequelize.col('bank.locationID') }
    }]
  }).then(function(banks) {
    res.render('index', { 
      title: 'Solar Data Savings',
      banks: banks
    });
  });
});

module.exports = router;
```

index.pug:

```
extends layout

block content
  div(class="container-fluid")
    h1= title
    p This is the #{title} project website
    form(action="/savings")
      div(class="form-group")
        label(for="locations")
        div(class="col-sm-4")
          select(id="locations" class="form-control")
            -for(var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
              option(value="#{locations[i].dataValues.locationID") #{locations[i].getLocationName()}
            -}
        div(class="col-sm-4")
          input(type="submit", value="Get Bank")
```

I believe I am misunderstanding a nuance to routing, and I've scoured the web for a solution to this particular problem with no luck. Help greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your savings route on the server is set to `/savings/savings` whereas your form is calling `/savings`. Either change the form or change the server side:

In **savings.js**, change

```
router.get('/savings', function(req....
```

to

```
router.get('/', function(req....
```

Also, you are using `get` to submit a form. Maybe you need to change that to

```
router.post('/', function(req...
```

Comment: Thank you, I should've caught that (:
Also I was using post originally just to try and trigger the route, I removed the form (because nothing needs to be persisted from the user) and replaced the submit button with a link.

Answer (score 0):

Just make following changes in **index.pug** :

```
extends layout
 block content
  div(class="container-fluid")
   h1= title
   p This is the #{title} project website
   form(action="/savings/savings")
     div(class="form-group")
      label(for="locations")
       div(class="col-sm-4")
        select(id="locations" class="form-control")
         -for(var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
          option(value="#{locations[i].dataValues.locationID") #{locations[i].getLocationName()}
         -}
       div(class="col-sm-4")
        input(type="submit", value="Get Bank")
```

Actually your routing is wrong:

> Currently you're calling as : **your_url:port/savings**
>
> BUT Should be : **your_url:port/savings/savings**

**LINE NEEDS CORRECTION**

> FROM : form(action="/savings")
>
> TO : form(action="/savings/savings")

Comment: I upvoted because this was also helpful, but since I'm new it won't display. Thanks!

Comment: you can do it later anytime BUT impressed by your honesty :) :)

Comment: Ok will do. And sure thing!